# reconnect a disconnected client socket

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets

Is it possible to reconnect an already disconnected socket without having to create a new socket FD?

Example:

```
int s = socket();
connect(s,...);
....
socket disconnects
....
connect(s,...);   <-------
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/connect.2.html), "Generally, stream sockets may successfully connect() only once; datagram sockets may use connect() multiple times to change their association." So if your socket is a TCP socket, the answer is "probably not"; if it's a UDP socket, the answer is "probably".

Comment: What do they mean by generally?

Comment: There may be exceptions. Maybe TCP is even one of them, although I wouldn't count on it.